# Zip File getting corrupted when i save it to isolated storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, zip, isolatedstorage

I have downloaded a zip file from blob storage and save it to isolated storage of windows phone like this :- FileStream fs is downloaded from blob.

```
public static void SaveToIsolatedStorage(FileStream fs, string fileName)
        {
            var isolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (var streamWriter =
                            new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fileName,
                                FileMode.Create,
                                FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                                isolatedStorage)))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(fs);
            }
        }
```

But when checked this zip file using IsoStoreSpy it is showing corrupted. I have checked it by reading from isolated storage and tried to unzip it but not working. I am sure that it is corrupted because when i replace this file using IsoStoreSpy with some other zip and then tried to unzip it then it is working.

**Edit**:-

Code for downloading from Blob

```
private async Task DownloadFileFromBlobStorage()
    {
        var filename = "AppId_2.zip";
        var blobContainer = GetBlobClient.GetContainerReference("testwpclientiapcontainer");
        var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);

        using (var filestream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(filestream);

            SaveToIsolatedStorage(filestream, filename);
        }
    }
```

So anybody know how can i save the zip file to isolated storage without getting it corrupted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a `StreamWriter`. That's for *text*. You shouldn't be using it to copy a zip file at all. Never use any `TextWriter` for binary data.

Next you're using `StreamWriter.Write(object)`, which is basically going to call `ToString` on the `FileStream`. That's not going to work either.

You should just create an `IsolatedStorageStream`, and then call `fs.CopyTo(output)`.

```
public static void SaveToIsolatedStorage(Stream input, string fileName)
{
    using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        // Simpler than calling the IsolatedStorageFileStream constructor...
        using (var output = storage.CreateFile(fileName))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

In your edit you've shown code which saves to a `FileStream` first, and then copies the stream *from the current position*. As you've noted in comments, you needed to rewind it first.

Personally I wouldn't use a `FileStream` at all here - why do you want to save it as a normal file *and* an isolated file? Just use a `MemoryStream`:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(filestream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    SaveToIsolatedStorage(stream, filename);
}
```

(Note that your `SaveToIsolatedStorage` method is still synchronous... you may wish to consider an asynchronous version.)

Comment: Jon it is not working :( I have made an edit to add code for downloading from blob.

Comment: FileStream position is not set to zero. I have added it as a comment in your ans. It is a working solution :)

Comment: @loop: Well, you wouldn't necessarily want to check that the position is 0. I would expect a method like this to copy "whatever's left in the stream". In fact, there's no need to require it to be a `FileStream` (will edit).